# Propel validation error with different objects

Tags: php, validation, email, propel

we're using a custom email validator and we're having a problem validating two different objects which have a relation to the same object.

Here is the example code:

```
$ti = EnumTipoInteresadoQuery::create()->findOne();

$i1 = new Interesado();
$i1->setTipoInteresado($ti);
$i1->setMail('testexample.com');
var_dump($i1->validate()); // Must be false and we get false. OK!

$i2 = new Interesado();
$i2->setTipoInteresado($ti);
$i2->setMail('hello@example.com');
var_dump($i2->validate()); // Must be true but we get false. BAD!
```

When we validate the first one ($i1) everything goes ok. When we validate the second one ($i2) we get false when we should get true!

Inside the custom validator we echoed a message with the string that gets validated:

```
class EmailValidator implements BasicValidator
{
  public function isValid(ValidatorMap $map, $str)
  {
    echo "Validating $str\n";
    return preg_match('/^([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})$/i', $str) !== 0;
  }
}
```

Looking at the output we see the following:

```
Validating testexample.com
bool(false)
Validating testexample.com
Validating hello@example.com
bool(false)
```

We can clearly see that the second validation ($i2) calls the custom validator twice, first with the mail of the first object ($i1) and then with the mail of the second ($i2).

We suspect that, as the two objects have a reference to a common object ($ti) the validation somehow "cascades" and validates the first ($i1) and second ($i2) object.

Is there any workaround for this issue? Is it a bug? Is it something we're doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Andrés